# Grouping rectangles (getting the bounding boxes of rects)

Tags: algorithm, geometry, collision-detection, bounding-box

What is a good, fast way to get the "final" bounding boxes of a set of random (up to about 40, not many) rectangles? By final I mean that all bounding boxes don't intersect with any other.

EDIT: my first example was wrong. The result I'm looking for is a group of rects, where each group forms a solid geometry when overlapped; they are not separate.

Because the rects are random every time, and the rect count is relatively small, collision detection using spatial hashing seems like overkill. Is there a way to do this more effectively?

Another example: There are 3 rects A, B and C. A intersects with B, but not with C. C intersects with B. These should be considered 1 group, because they form a single geometry.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Can the bounding boxes intersect? In other words, is your definition of a group a) every rectangle intersects with at least another rectangle in the group, or b) rectangles have to intersect with one another or have to intersect with the group's bounding box?

Comment: I don't understand.  Isn't bounding box just a box containing all of your rectangles?

Comment: No. He's looking for groups of rectangles. What I'm asking is... imagine your entire screen, each pixel being a rectangle. Draw a line from the upper left corner to the bottom right, and eliminate the rectangles (pixels) that the line touches. You have two sets of pixels (rectangles) left, one in the upper right, one in the lower left. By your definition, is it one group (bounding boxes can't intersect), or is it two groups (bounding boxes can intersect). The "how to" depends on this.

Comment: Err actually, the resulting bounding boxes CAN intersect, but the actual geometry cannot. I am looking for groups where a) every rectangle intersects with at least another rectangle in the group, but also the rects in each group must form 1 solid geometry; they can't be separate.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare every rectangle *after* the current one. E.G. If you have and Array [A,B,C]

If you compare A,B you don't need to compare B,A or B,B only B,C. If nothing else changes this will reduce the number of iterations.

You can do this by starting the inner for loop at the current index of the outter.